# Theorem 8.1.1 of Øksendal textbook

Tags: measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stopping-times, stochastic-differential-equations

I have troubles understanding part (b) of the proof to Theorem 8.1.1 in the Øksendal textbook (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-14394-6)

The theorem is as follows:

Let $X_t$ be an Itô diffusion in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with generator $A$ and $f\in C_0^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

(a):

Define
\begin{equation*}
u(t,x)=E^x[f(X_t)].
\end{equation*}
Then $u(t,\cdot)\in\mathcal{D}_A$ for each $t$ and
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=Au,~ t>0,~x\in\mathbb{R}^n\\
u(0,x)=f(x),~x\in\mathbb{R}^n
\end{align}
where the right hand side is to be interpreted as $A$ applied to the function $x\mapsto u(t,x)$.

(b):

Moreover, if $w(t,x)\in C^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a bounded function satisfying
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial w}{\partial t}=Aw,~ t>0,~x\in\mathbb{R}^n\\
w(0,x)=f(x),~x\in\mathbb{R}^n
\end{align}
then $w(t,x)=u(t,x)$.

The proof of part (b) starts as follows:

Fix $(s,x)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n$. Define the process $Y_t$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ by $Y_t=(s-t,X_t^x)$, $t\geq 0$. Then $Y_t$ has generator $\tilde{A}$ with
\begin{equation*}
\tilde{A}w(t,x)=-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}w(t,x)+Aw(t,x)=0,~t>0,~x\in\mathbb{R}^n.
\end{equation*}
By Dynkin's formula we have for all $t\geq 0$
\begin{equation*}
E^{(s,x)}[w(Y_{t\wedge\tau_R)})]=w(s,x)+E^{(s,x)}\left[\int_0^{t\wedge\tau_R}\tilde{A}w(Y_r)dr\right],
\end{equation*}
where $\tau_R:=\inf\{t>0||X_t|\geq R\}$.

Now we want to conclude that
\begin{equation*}
E^{(s,x)}[w(Y_{t\wedge\tau_R)})]=w(s,x).
\end{equation*}
It seems as Øksendal uses the fact that $\tilde{A}$ vanishes, but this is only the case for $t>0$, so the first component of $Y_r$ has to be positiv? But why is this the case? Or what do I misunderstand?

Comment: Do you realize that your question can be answered only by those users who have access to Øksendal's textbook?

Comment: With the comment by @AnotherUser: I have the text, but don't want to dig it out now. Please make your question self-contained by stating the theorem.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

In the integral $0<r<t\wedge\tau_R\le t$, so the first component of $Y_r$, namely $s-r$, is in the interval $(s-t,s)$. You are right to be wary: Øksendal's deduction of the second equality in the formula appearing in the first display following (8.1.6) requires $t$ to be at most $s$. But this restriction is okay, because the identity is subsequently used only for $t=s$.